# How to record entire browsing history in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, history

How does one record and view the entire browsing history in Firefox? I'm thinking of some sort of table containing an entry every time I load page, including basics like page title, visit timestamp, URL.

As far as I'm aware, the standard Firefox history (accessible via the GUI) only records, for any given URL, the time of the most recent visit. The GUI seems to access a SQL table, and that SQL table does not contain any information outside of what can be seen in the GUI. The SQL table I'm referring to is placed (on UNIX-based systems) at

```
/home/$USER/.mozilla/firefox/$PROFILE.default/places.sqlite
```

I am hoping to see separate entries each time I visit the same URL. Is this exposed anywhere within Firefox?

If it's relevant I am on Xubuntu.

Comment: I understand how the original question can be viewed as close-ended. I was hoping to hear discussion on how other users may have attempted to extract this information from Firefox. I am happy to hear things other than recommendations of particular add-ons, of course, but would be satisfied even to hear that someone has achieved it **at all**.

Comment: A possible solution (in the form of a local addon) is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/671473).